# Disable "Display intranet sites in Compat. View" from within the code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

[image]

How do I uncheck this box from within the code base? My Highchart won't render and it's because of this tab.

The `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` isn't working and I've removed all of the header data except the `js` and `css` imports from the `iframe`.\

**Main Page Header**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

**iframe header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/site/css/graphs.css" type="text/css"/>
<link REL="stylesheet" href="/public/site/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/site/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/site/js/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">...code...</script>
```

Comment: could you take a look to "How to disable Compatibility View in IE"

Comment: @gaemaf `How do I uncheck this box from within the code base?`  I know how to do it within the browser, that wasn't my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but from the code base you cannot change the ie box option. Instead, have you tried to add  your line "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">" inside the iframe? I'm curious.

Comment: @gaemaf I did. But it wasn't working because in IE 9 iframes inherit from the parent

Comment: For security reasons, you cannot change browser settings with JavaScript.  There's no public API.  You can use `x-ua-compatible` to nominate a preference, but the user's configuration choices have the final say.  (Having said that, you can use group policies to prevent user choice, but that's not something that's open to JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you put <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> in the main page instead of in the iframe, if that's possible. IE can't use a different document mode between the main page and a frame or iframe.